# How to write query to make result of a key with cardinality/many be a map while not a vector in datascript

Tags: clojurescript, datascript

Assume a datascript db has a schema:

```
(def schema {:maker/cars {:db/cardinality :db.cardinality/many
                          :db/valueType :db.type/ref}})
(def conn (d/create-conn schema)
```

And has inserted some entities:

```
{:db/id 1
 :car/name "x"}
{:db/id 2
 :car/name "y"}
{:db/id 3
 :car/name "z"}
{:db/id 4 
 :maker/name "Honda"
 :maker/cars [1 2 3]}
```

Then the query

```
(d/q '[:find [(pull ?e [:maker/name  {:maker/cars [:car/name]}])]
                 :where [?e :maker/name "Honda"]] @conn)
```

will get the result:

```
[#:maker{:name "Honda",
     :cars [#:car{:name "x"} #:car{:name "y"} #:car{:name "z"}]}]
```

The `:maker/cars` is a vector.

How to write the pull query to get the result like below?

```
[#:maker{:name "Honda",
     :cars {1 #:car{:name "x"}
            2 #:car{:name "y"}
            3 #:car{:name "z"}}]
```

Tried but got no lucky...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s no way. There aren’t many options to control the shape of data Pull API returns. Just do your own post-processing on a result that DataScript returns

Comment: well, since the creator has said that then it must be correct :)